# How can I get win32pdhutil to query a performance counter with a slash?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to query Windows Performance Counters using **win32pdhutil** from the pywin32 package in Python, but I run into an error whenever the counter name has a slash.

For example, this code works fine:

```
import win32pdhutil

query = win32pdhutil.GetPerformanceAttributes("Memory", "Available Bytes")
```

But this code fails:

```
import win32pdhutil

query = win32pdhutil.GetPerformanceAttributes("Memory", "Cache Faults/sec")
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32pdhutil.py", line 61, in GetPerformanceAttributes
    type, val = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue(hc, format)
pywintypes.error: (-1073738810, 'GetFormattedCounterValue', 'The data is not valid.')
```

I've tried a number of different counters and only run into this issue when there is a slash in the counter name.

My original code uses win32pdh.AddCounter and win32pdh.CollectQueryData with the same issue, but the example above demonstrates it in a single line.

I found a similar thread [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2011-March/011382.html), without an obvious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for "cache faults/sec" to collect enough data, Here is an c++ sample on msdn for Performance Counters api:

[Browsing Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/browsing-performance-counters)

And in python, if I hard code(just for test) in `GetPerformanceAttributes` function in win32pdhutil.py as below:

```
def GetPerformanceAttributes(object, counter, instance = None, inum=-1,
                             format = win32pdh.PDH_FMT_LONG, machine=None):
    # NOTE: Many counters require 2 samples to give accurate results,
    # including "% Processor Time" (as by definition, at any instant, a
    # thread's CPU usage is either 0 or 100).  To read counters like this,
    # you should copy this function, but keep the counter open, and call
    # CollectQueryData() each time you need to know.
    # See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q262938
    # and http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/dnperfmo/html/perfmonpt2.asp
    # My older explanation for this was that the "AddCounter" process forced
    # the CPU to 100%, but the above makes more sense :)
    path = win32pdh.MakeCounterPath( (machine,object,instance, None, inum,counter) )
    hq = win32pdh.OpenQuery()
    try:
        hc = win32pdh.AddCounter(hq, path)
        try:
            win32pdh.CollectQueryData(hq)
            time.sleep(1)
            win32pdh.CollectQueryData(hq)
            type, val = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue(hc, format)
            return val
        finally:
            win32pdh.RemoveCounter(hc)
    finally:
        win32pdh.CloseQuery(hq)
```

Then `"Cache Faults/sec"` works for me, you could try to customize your own `m_GetFormattedCounterValue` function, and then give the collector enough time to collect data like the sample above.