# How do I get SQL performance counter counter values (Exclusively Number of active connection pools)

Tags: python, sql-server, ado.net

I need NumberOfActive connection pools value out of all the Available Performance Counters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters). Is there any way to capture the value using python. If not SQL can I get exact SQL query.

Comment: It's not an SQL Server counter, it comes from the client driver. Apparently there is a Python library to read perf counters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535396/how-can-i-get-win32pdhutil-to-query-a-performance-counter-with-a-slash the category name is `.NET Data Provider for SqlServer` the counter name is `NumberOfActiveConnectionPools` and the instance name is the friendly name of the AppDomain. But why you would want to do this from Python I don't know, it's probably much easier from C#, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters

Comment: I want to send NumberOfActiveConnectionPools pool data to APM tool. I want this data to be populated in APM tool and set the alerts/tickets. I will use python SDK to push the data. So, that's the reason I was looking for python solution.